# Changing Font Colour in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, css

My Problem is that I have modified the CoreV4.css to custom colours. However, when a particular item in a list or library is selected (checked), the font colour of the item matches the background colour. I tried searching for the css class of selected items but could not find much. Any help on this topic is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this class:

```
tr.s4-itm-selected > td, tr.s4-itm-selected:hover > td {
    border-bottom-color: #529DCC !important;
    border-top-color: #A5CCE4 !important;
    color: #003759 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot andrew. Although this only partially solved my problem. I guess I need to be clearer. The above class only modified my item names and not the hyperlinks in the item. Could anyone of you maybe post the class for doing the same with links??

Comment: Solved it. The tag was tr.s4-itm-selected a. Thanks a lot